# Dynamic pandas dataframe filter not working

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I can't get this dynamic filter work

**df_dates**

```
print(df_dates)

    Type  Entry      Exit 
    0     2008-03-03 2008-03-17  
    1     2010-05-19 2010-06-10
```

**This hardcoded filter is working**

```
df_to_filter = df_to_filter[
    (df_to_filter['date']>='2008-03-03 00:00:00') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2008-03-17 00:00:00') | 
    (df_to_filter['date']>='2010-05-19 00:00:00') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2010-06-10 00:00:00')
]
```

**Dynamic filter not working, the string seems to be exactly the same**

```
df_str = "df_to_filter['date']"
    
filter_mask = ' | '.join(f'({df_str}>=\'{start}\') & ({df_str}<=\'{stop}\')' for start,stop in zip(df_dates['Entry'],df_dates['Exit']))
filter_mask = filter_mask + ']'

print(filter_mask)

(df_to_filter['date']>='2008-03-03 00:00:00') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2008-03-17 00:00:00') | (df_to_filter['date']>='2010-05-19 00:00:00') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2010-06-10 00:00:00')]
    
df_to_filter = df_to_filter[filter_mask]
```

**Error**

```
KeyError: "(df_to_filter['date']>='2008-03-03 00:00:00') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2008-03-17 00:00:00') | (df_to_filter['date']>='2010-05-19 00:00:00') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2010-06-10 00:00:00')]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have  for example dataframes:

`df_dates:`

```
Type  Entry      Exit 
0     2008-03-03 2008-03-17  
1     2010-05-19 2010-06-10
```

`df_to_filter:`

```
date
2008-03-03 
2010-06-11
```

Then You can filter it using `filter_mask` expression:

```
filter_mask = ' | '.join(f'({df_str}>=\'{start}\') & ({df_str}<=\'{stop}\')' for start,stop in zip(df_dates['Entry'],df_dates['Exit']))
"(df_to_filter['date']>='2008-03-03') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2008-03-17') | (df_to_filter['date']>='2010-05-19') & (df_to_filter['date']<='2010-06-10')"

print(df_to_filter[eval(filter_mask)])
```

result:

```
         date
0  2008-03-03
```

To call literal expression `eval()` function is needed.

Comment: Thanks @lpj. i've forgot mention that my dataframe is a dask dataframe, is not working with a dask dataframe, i am wondering why not.

Comment: It is important detail indeed :-) So consider accepting this answer regarding Pandas dataframe and ask another question specifying that You are working in dask environment.